# Websocket error during connection between .net core 3.1 and Angular with Signalr

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I have created a .net core web api project and trying to use SignalR and connecting to an Angular app.

I am getting an error while making a connection with Angular.

```
WebSocketTransport.js:85 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:44363/api/message' failed: Error during 
WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

My startup.cs

```
namespace SignalR_server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
            });

            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");


            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>("/message");
            });
        }                                                                                           
    }
}
```

and MessageController.cs

```
public class MessageController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IHubContext<MessageHub> _myHub; 

        public MessageController(IHubContext<MessageHub> hub)
        {
            _myHub = hub;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public Message Get()
        {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.Id = 1;
            msg.Name = "name";
            msg.Msg = "This is a test message";
            _myHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transfermessage", msg);
            return msg;
        }
```

In my client-side connection, I made skipNegotiation as true

```
  public startConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .withUrl('https://localhost:44363/api/message',{
                              skipNegotiation: true,
                              transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
                            })
                            .build();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: why `/api/message`? your path seems to be `/message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the code `endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>("/message")`, you set "/message" as your complete path. Your signalr hub endpoint would hence be 'https://localhost:44363/message', not 'https://localhost:44363/api/message'.

In the future when you see an "expected 200", make sure you check the network tab of your browser's developer tools. This tab will show you the real error you got. In this case, I assume you would have got a 404.